# array displays the wrong thing

Tags: javascript, html

I want this code to display information from a text input from a form on an HTML page, using the array, it would take the information into an array, then display it back on a textarea, though each time it overrides the first line, not displaying right

```
var count = 0;

var input = document.forms["ShoppingForm"]["choiceTxt"].value;

function listChoice(){

    count++;
    var arr = new Array();
    arr[count] = document.forms["ShoppingForm"]["choiceTxt"].value + "\n";
    for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
        document.forms["ShoppingForm"]["listDisplay"].value = count + ". " + 
        arr[i] + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: please share the html code

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with this line `var arr = new Array();`. Everytime it will create a new array.

Try my declaring the array outside the function.Also the seems to be no need of the `count`. The value can be simply pushed in the array

```
var count = 0;
var arr = [];
var input = document.forms["ShoppingForm"]["choiceTxt"].value;

function listChoice(){
    arr.push(document.forms["ShoppingForm"]["choiceTxt"].value + "\n");
    for(var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++){
        document.forms["ShoppingForm"]["listDisplay"].value = count + ". " + 
        arr[i] + "\n";
    }
}
```